# C# Tesseract OCR not reading image in build .exe

Tags: c#, build, ocr, tesseract, nuget-package

I have a C# program that uses IronTesseract OCR. Everything works fine when running the program inside Visual Studio, but when running **Ocr.Read()** from the build .exe, the code does not execute and gets stuck at that point.

The weird thing is that when attaching the debugger from visual studio to the running .exe, the **Ocr.Read()** code executes normally. I am not using #IF DEBUG anywhere, so I'm not too sure if I'm missing something.

Everything else works normally on the build.

Thanks in advance for any help, I'm more than happy to provide more information.

Comment: How big is the file you're trying to read?  Do you see a live handle, I/O in System Informer or some such task manager?

Comment: @GregC the file shouldn't be too large, it's a print screen of a window, not being saved anywhere, maybe that's part of the issue? Should I be saving and then reading the file as opposed to reading directly from an unsaved bitmap image?

Comment: Using IronOCR by IronSoftware 2022.11.10109. for .NET 6 Windows Desktop yes

Comment: Not sure how to test out the sample code, unless you just mean the code on that page. But the code works perfectly fine when running from visual studio, or when visual studio is attached to the built .exe. The problem is the code running with the build .exe alone. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok just a really stupid mistake from my side. I put the code into a try catch and found the following error:

"IronOCR must be licensed outside of the Visual Studio development environment."

I'll be looking into licensing, thanks for the help though.